# How do I make gradle run print out all lines of the stacktrace?

Tags: gradle

`gradle run --full-stacktrace`

> at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
>           ... 33 more

How do I get the 33 next lines? 
It seems to run on other environments so I'm just debugging why my application doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a scan will publish a report that prints the full stack trace. Stack trace wasn't very helpful though.

gradle run --scan